# Group and Color Code Categories in Pivot Tables/Charts Excel

Tags: excel, charts, ms-office, pivot-table

I have data in a pivot table as follows:

[image: pivot table with categories labelled 1.1, 1.2 etc]

I'd like to group the data as shown in the brackets (all the 1s, 2s, and 3s together) *without* combining the data, and have it be color coded ideally, rather than the random colors it currently is. Is there a way to do this? I come upon this problem a lot and end up manually fixing the graphs, so I'm hoping to save some time!

Comment: Try a helper column in your data, that is then added to the pivot. Basically it would be a group assignment for each of the data sets. Give it a meaningful name of course. Then you can control the display of the groups and the data within them.